# Can I use ifsym clock in Tikz picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, overleaf

I created a matrix and want to show clock above the matrix in Tikz picture. I found ifsym clock package with quite easy implementation, but I wonder how to use it in Tikz.

```
\ClockFrametrue\ClockStyle=1\clock{12}{0}
```

Looking for the suitable answer.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! As content of node?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry did not see @Zarkos comment.But as he suggested simply draw it as a node.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{clock}
\usepackage[clock]{ifsym}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
    \node[xshift=-2mm](A) at (0,0) {\ClockFrametrue\ClockStyle=1\clock{12}{0}};
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]